# Adding modifiers (is, is not, contains, etc.) to custom SmartTarget Triggers

Tags: web8.5, smarttarget, experience-optimization

Some of the default SmartTarget / Experience Optimisation Triggers have modifiers/conditions on their rules.

For example, when using the **Number of results** Trigger, there is a dropdown with the following options:

- is above or equal
- is below
- is
- is not
- is between

[image: Screenshot of SmartTarget Trigger modifiers]

My question is whether it is possible to add these (or similar) options for Custom Triggers.

For example, I would like my rule to be: "... Where segment **is not** 'Control Group'"

I have the following in my **trigger-types.xml**:

```
<trigger-type basetype="text" url-param="client_segment" name="User Segment">
  <list-of-values>
    <value>Under 40</value>
    <value>Over 40</value>
    <value>Control Group</value>
  </list-of-values>
</trigger-type>
```

I've looked in the [Defining Trigger types](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-BE71C97B-F372-4B76-AD38-D56D2BD418E2) documentation, but cannot see this as an option.

Q1. Is it possible?

Q2. If it is possible, how is it achieved and what are the constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to define which operators are available for your trigger. It is based entirely on the basetype of the trigger type (text, float, etc.). This is a limitation of Fredhopper.

As such, the only way to choose "Segment is not 'Control Group'" would be to select every other Segment in the Promotion editing screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Peter. That's kind of the conclusion I was coming to (with some help from Neil Gibbons). Unfortunately, sometimes the Segment will not be populated (i.e. null and no value at all), but I still want to trigger the Promotion. Therefore, in this case I think we'll need an explicit 'Not Control Group' segment.